# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.Include from [Module \"deployment.myproject_dev.war\" from Service Modu

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am running a web project using IntelliJ and wildfly server. I have set up the project using the guidelines of the company, when I run wilfly server from intellij, I get the following error:

```
00:14:42,487 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myproject_dev.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject_dev.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myprjoject_dev.war\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.Include from [Module \"deployment.myprojct_dev.war\" from Service Module Loader]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.Include from [Module \"deployment.myproject_dev.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
```

After that I go to the deployed war folder to check If I have jersy stuff in the libs and it seems to be there in war/WEB-INF/lib:

jersey-common.jar jersey-entity-filtering.jar jersey-hk2.jar jersey-media-json-jackson.jar jersey-media-multipart.jar

For me it seems that the applications expects a Jersey 1.x  (as the error msg suggests – com.sun.jersey) but I have in the library Jersey 2.x (which is correct). why does the application expect jersey 1.x ?

dependency:tree print following:

```
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.35:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.35:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.35:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.35:provided
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with `mvn dependency:tree` if your dependency is imported as a transitive dependency. If so, you would have to exclude it from the dependency that imports it.